How to Update an Account in CyberArk
I am trying to update the CyberArk Account using its API.
I am following the doc Update Account
The HTTP method is PATCH according to the documentation.
I am trying to make a simple update on my account, following the example from the cyberark docs.
# Update Account Payload
update_account_payload = {
    "address": UAT,
    "userName": "username",
    "platformId": "platform_id",
    "safeName": "safe_name",
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/address",
    "value": "QA"
}




update_response = requests.patch(add_account_url, headers=headers, json=update_account_payload, verify=False)
print("---Response from Server Update Account---:", update_response.text)

I am getting the below error when I am running the above.

{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'PATCH'."}

I do not know what I am missing here.
